# Django Admin validation

Tags: regex, django, validation, django-models, django-admin

I'd like to validate user input with regular expression in Django Admin CharField... How is it possible?

Thanks in advance,
Etam.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Define a custom form for your model admin, and override the specific field to use a [`RegexField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.1/ref/forms/fields/#regexfield).

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    myfield = models.CharField(max_length=10)


class MyModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    myfield = forms.RegexField(regex=r'\w+')


class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModelForm

admin.site.register(MyModel, MyModelAdmin)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use clean method in ur form and validiate the fields using regex.That will form validiation.You can raise error on what u want